Function thinks it has poles until you expand
Below I have a function func, which I have to evaluate thousands of times for various values of l,m,x. At the value x=0, the Mathematica says the function goes to complex infinity until you expand it first at the l and m values then sub in the x value. I would rather not expand each time I wish to evaluate this function at x==0. Is there some workaround to make Mathematica realise what mistake it's making?
func[l_, m_, x_] := 
 4/(m + 2) (Cos[x/2])^(m + 2)
   Sum[(((-1)^k (l + k)!)/(l - k)! Hypergeometric2F1[(m + 2)/2, 
     m/2 - k, (m + 4)/2, Cos[x/2]^2])/(Gamma[k - m + 1] k!), {k, 0, l}]

In[509]:= (func[12, 10, x] // Expand) /. x -> 0

Out[509]= 3907008000

In[511]:= func[12, 10, 0]

During evaluation of In[511]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[511]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[511]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.

During evaluation of In[511]:= General::stop: Further output of Infinity::indet will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[511]= Indeterminate
```


Just take a limit: Limit[l,m,x],x->0].

There is no mistake MMA is making, $p/p$ for $p=0$ is simply undefined.
Now taking limits/expanding, it can do just fine. So I have encountered the same problem and my very crude solution is to define a Piecewise function, where you make the cases for which there a limits to be taken explicit.
E.g. for $a\frac{\sin x}{x}$:
Piecewise[{{a Sin[x}/x,x!=0}},a].
Better solutions are appreciated
